# How to add column and change column name?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want "select" to be in its own column, how does that work?

Also I want to change the column name, it currently labeled "Item" where I do not know where comes from.

[image]

```
string Name = row["Server"].ToString();
            string Ip= row["Ip"].ToString();
            string Id = row["User"].ToString();
            string Port = row["Port"].ToString();
            string Password = row["Password"].ToString();

            string credentials = $"server={Ip}; user id={Id}; port={Port}; Password={Password}";

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(credentials);
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);


            adp.Fill(ds); //Fill Dataset.
            dt = ds.Tables[0]; //Then assign table to dt.

            foreach(DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows) //Checks the server if it is running or not.
            {
                string value = dataRow.Field<string>("Slave_IO_Running"); //Looks for "Slave_IO_Running" status.

                if (value == "Yes")
                {
                    status.Add(Name + ": Working");
                }
                else
                {
                    status.Add(Name + ": Replication ERR");
                }
                break;
            }

            GridView1.DataSource = status;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Can you share the aspx code too?

Comment: Im not allowed to add more code so here is a pic https://i.imgur.com/g6hhNvC.png

Comment: The image is very low quality. Nothing visible

Answer (score 0):

You're passing **status** variable as your DataSource, so your GridView displays what **status** contains. To add or rename columns in GridView you should take a closer look at that variable.

If you want more help please post the part of code where you initialize that variable.

However, you should read about GridView and understand better how it works. You can check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/gridview-overview).

Comment: Do you mean this?    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            BindData();        
    }

Comment: `GridView1.DataSource = status`  here you set your DataSource(what is displayed by the GridView). Where you create **status**? We only see where you add data to it ( `status.Add(Name + ": Working")` ).